# How to make an object list from double values?

Tags: java

I have a list of doubles.

```
List<Double> averagesAndSums = new ArrayList<>();
```

which has 20 double values. These values are average and sum values of Invoice objects.

```
public class Invoice {
    private double average;
    private double sum;

//const, getters, setters
}
```

Thus it has a structure like that

```
index 0 = average, index 1 = sum, index 2= average, index 3 = sum, 
index 4 = average, index 5 = sum ... so on.
```

How can I make a list of 10 invoice object from these average and sum values?

Comment: x*2 are always even numbers, x*2 + 1 always odd.

Comment: How does the `Invoice` look? What have you tried so far? May the `List<Double>` grow beyond 20 items somewhen in the future?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do odd even filtering using streams, e.g.:

```
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(1d, 5d, 3d, 6d);

List<Double> averages = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
        .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Double> sums = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
        .filter(i -> (i % 2 != 0))
        .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**

Once you have two lists, if you want `Invoice` object, you can stream over one list and construct the object, e.g.:

```
List<Invoice> invoices = IntStream.range(0, sums.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Invoice(averages.get(i), sums.get(i)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update2**

As @ernest_k suggested, this can also be done in a single iteration, e.g.:

```
List<Invoice> invoices2 = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0))
    .mapToObj(i -> new Invoice(list.get(i), list.get(i + 1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: and then you need to zip these two lists again into Invoice objects.

Comment: @Thilo looks like the question was updated since I posted the answer.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta How can i zip them together? A flatmap?

Comment: @AdamJungen added that bit.

Comment: You can also use just one stream here: `IntStream.range(0, list.size()).filter(i -> (i % 2 == 0)) .mapToObj(i -> new Invoice(list.get(i), list.get(i+1)))...`

Comment: @ernest_k added your inputs to the answer.

Comment: Thanx @ernest_k that was the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
List<Invoice> result = new ArrayList<>(averageAndSums.size() / 2);
for (int i = 0; i < averageAndSums.size(); i += 2){
    result.add(new Invoice(averageAndSums.get(i), averageAndSums.get(i + 1)));
}
```

But how did this oddly shaped list come about in the first place?

Comment: I was late! : )

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 solution (without forming additional lists for `avarages` and `sums`):

```
List<Invoice> invoices = 
   IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2)
            .limit(averageAndSums.size() / 2)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Invoice(averageAndSums.get(i), averageAndSums.get(i + 1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<Invoice> invoiceList = new ArrayList<>(averageAndSums.size()/2);
for(int i = 0; i < averageAndSums.size(); i +=2 ) {
    Double avg = averageAndSums[i];
    Double sum = averageAndSums[i+1];
    invoiceList.add(new Invoice(avg, sum)); //Considering the Invoice class has the required constructor
}
```

Comment: Is it some new feature in recent JDK to access list by index? Referring to invoiceList[i/2]

Comment: edited and as each `Invoice` has two properties so the size of `averageAndSums` will be even.

Comment: i < averageAndSums.size() will lead to IndexOutofBoundException, should be i < averageAndSums.size() - 1